# SSRS report from cube parameter: text input field instead of drop-down menu

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx

Good afternoon,

I'm very new to MDX. Using Report Builder I created SSRS report based on cube data. All looks good and I'm able to add a parameter for this report too, but the problem is that I only managed to get it working as a drop-down menu. What I really need is it to work in a typical SSRS way - text input field.

So searching for an information I got an impression that the only way to achieve this is to amend dataset's MDX query and set the desired field as `StrToMember`. The most relevant example that I found was [this one](http://prologika.com/CS/forums/p/892/3266.aspx). Other examples on the internet weren't too helpful to me with the knowledge I have.

My question is: having this query, where/how should I use `StrToMember` to be able to use the field `[Inventory information].[Parent Item].[Parent Item]` as a free text parameter?

```
SELECT { } ON COLUMNS, { 
    ([Inventory information].[BOM].[BOM].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [Inventory information].[Item number].[Item number].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [Inventory information].[Line number].[Line number].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [Inventory information].[Parent Item].[Parent Item].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [Inventory information].[Product name].[Product name].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [Inventory information].[Quantity].[Quantity].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [Inventory information].[Sequence].[Sequence].ALLMEMBERS )}
        DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
        FROM [Inventory analysis] CELL PROPERTIES VALUE
```

This query doesn't return any errors, but at the same time it removes all fields from a dataset.

```
SELECT { } ON COLUMNS, { 
    ([Inventory information].[BOM].[BOM].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [Inventory information].[Item number].[Item number].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [Inventory information].[Line number].[Line number].ALLMEMBERS * 
    StrToMember ('[Inventory information].[Parent Item].[Parent Item].&[' + @InventoryinformationParentItem + ']') *
    [Inventory information].[Product name].[Product name].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [Inventory information].[Quantity].[Quantity].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [Inventory information].[Sequence].[Sequence].ALLMEMBERS )}
        DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
        FROM [Inventory analysis] CELL PROPERTIES VALUE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dataset is not identifying fields returned by your MDX script. I think you did not define the parameter in the designer. Add the parameter from the designer.

[image]

Try your query without an associated parameter.

```
SELECT { } ON COLUMNS, { 
    ([Inventory information].[BOM].[BOM].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [Inventory information].[Item number].[Item number].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [Inventory information].[Line number].[Line number].ALLMEMBERS * 
    StrToMember ("[Inventory information].[Parent Item].[Parent Item].&[" + "SomeString" + "]") *
    [Inventory information].[Product name].[Product name].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [Inventory information].[Quantity].[Quantity].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [Inventory information].[Sequence].[Sequence].ALLMEMBERS )}
        DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
        FROM [Inventory analysis] CELL PROPERTIES VALUE
```

Also I am unsure about your syntax in the Parent Item attribute you posted.

Try this:

```
StrToMember ("[Inventory information].[Parent Item].&[" + "SomeString" + "]")
```

Let me know if this can help you.

Comment: Thank you for your help, @Alejandro. Unfortunately your suggestions didn't worked. The first query I shared is being generated by query designer and I have had parameter defined. Altough, your suggestion didn't returned any error, it didn't returned any results either and fields are not being shown neither. 

Also, your second `StrToMember` suggestion returns syntax error, so the first one seemed to be correct.

Comment: @Donatas, connect to the cube via SSMS and try the query from there in order to see the error it throws. Remember use a hardcoded string as parameter. `StrToMember ("[Inventory information].[Parent Item].&[" + "SomeString" + "]")`

Comment: No errors, @Alejandro. That's what SSMS returns: _Executing the query ...
Obtained object of type: Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.CellSet
Formatting.
Cell set consists of 0 rows and 0 columns.
Done formatting.
Execution complete._

Comment: If I add `CONSTRAINED` to `StrToMember`, I get this error: _The restrictions imposed by the CONSTRAINED flag in the STRTOMEMBER function were violated._

Comment: If your query is not returning any rows, columns maybe you are using a member that doesn't exist in your dimension. If you use `StrToMember ("[Inventory information].[Parent Item].&[" + "SomeString" + "]")`. you have to replace `SomeString`by a valid member in your `Inventory Information` dimension.

Comment: Thank you, @Alejandro :) I've been trying what you've suggested from the beggining, but it didn't worked. And then I simply copied/pasted a member from a dimension to the query string. But instead of pasting just a member, it pasted whole path to it, and that's where I've noticed it is not the same as we used. So the correct path is `StrToMember ("[Inventory information].[Parent Item].&[companyName]&[" + "SomeString" + "]")`. Now it returns appropriate results in SSMS, so I'll try to get the free text input field working too. `[companyName]` bit is coming from Dynamics AX.

Comment: However, using a parameter instead of random string still doesn't return anything, I mean, no rows and columns. That's what I'm using `StrToMember ("[Inventory information].[Parent Item].&[companyName]&[" + @InventoryinformationParentItem + "]")`. Parameter's line is added in Query Parameters form, so I guess it's wrong syntax again...

Comment: @Donatas, I am unsure if SSRS can handle MDX scripts that doesn't return columns. Before I've encountered with some clients that cannot handle this situation. Try adding a measure on columns.

Comment: Thanks, @Alejandro. I've studied a MDX book this weekend and done what you suggested - I've added  all columns as measures too. So the result that I got is quite logical - instead of real values (names, IDs), I now have measures of type _Count_ for each field. Unfortunately, Dynamics AX generates cube only if _Count_ is chosen. So in SSMS I tried to make a query other way around - dimensions on columns and measures on rows. It works in SSMS, but in Query Designer it returns: _...The query must have at least one axis..._ The rest I got working, meaning, my free text filter is working.

Comment: @Donatas, I hope you have used my answer and my comments to solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, @Alejandro, thank you. You have helped me to find an answer to the initial question, even though I haven't achieved what I wanted yet :)